Serial voting was reversed
I see this notification that 150 points were deducted and reversed because of the reasons mentioned in https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed
I don't remember a single user voting randomly on my different answers in last month. Is it possible to get the details of this reversal?

No, unless someone told you themselves that they've been voting for you, there is no way to find out for a user who voted for them.

Hmm I was wondering if mods could see those details because the link I shared in question mentioned sometimes reversal can be manual and done by mods after investigation.
